# Selecting multiple rows in feature based on contents of list using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, select-by-attribute, select-by-expression

I am trying to select rows in a feature layer in QGIS based on the values in a list. I am using PyQGIS in the python console

If I just specify one item to find in a column called "gps_code", the feature(s) are selected

I would like to pass a list of items to achieve a selection of features based on that list and have tried to use a list comprehension for this but I am not getting the desired result

```
layer.selectByExpression('"gps_code" = \'DAAG\'')
iface.showAttributeTable(layer)

list_of_sites = ['DAAG', 'ENTC', 'ENBR']
layer.selectByExpression('"gps_code" = \'s\' for s in list_of_sites')
iface.showAttributeTable(layer)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using format and `IN` operator like:

```
list_of_sites = ('Arvika' , 'Avesta' , 'Arboga') #Note the tuple () and not list []
processing.run("qgis:selectbyexpression", 
    {'INPUT':'C:/GIS/data/testdata/ak_riks.shp',
    'EXPRESSION':'"KOMMUNNAMN" IN{0}'.format(list_of_sites),
    'METHOD':0})
```

You can also list ids and select by them:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
list_of_sites = ['Arvika', 'Avesta', 'Arboga' ]
fieldname = "KOMMUNNAMN"
lyr.select([f.id() for f in lyr.getFeatures() if f[fieldname] in list_of_sites])
```

[image]